# Is there a priority to JPA Querydsl's orderBy?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sql-order-by, querydsl

I have a simple table called Member

| id | username | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | member17 | 25 |
| 2 | member18 | 24 |
| 3 | member19 | 23 |
| 4 | member20 | 22 |
| 5 | null | 21 |
| 6 | member22 | 21 |
| 7 | member23 | 21 |
| 8 | member24 | 18 |
| 9 | null | 17 |

I was practicing sorting with Querydsl with this simple sorting query.

```
    @Override
    public List<Member> sortMemberList() {
        return queryFactory
                .selectFrom(member)
                .where(member.age.between(17, 25))
                .orderBy(
                        member.age.asc(),
                        member.username.asc().nullsLast()
                )
                .fetch();
    }
```

This query produces

```
    select
        m1_0.member_id,
        m1_0.age,
        m1_0.team_id,
        m1_0.username 
    from
        Member m1_0 
    where
        m1_0.age between ? and ? 
    order by
        m1_0.age,
        case 
            when (m1_0.username) is null then 1 
            else 0 
        end,
        m1_0.username
```

As you can see, `member.age.asc()` and `member.username.asc()` are two directly opposite sorts. But for the result, I see,

```
[
    {
        "username": null,
        "age": 17
    },
    {
        "username": "member24",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "username": "member22",
        "age": 21
    },
    {
        "username": "member23",
        "age": 21
    },
    {
        "username": null,
        "age": 21
    },
    {
        "username": "member20",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "username": "member19",
        "age": 23
    },
    {
        "username": "member18",
        "age": 24
    },
    {
        "username": "member17",
        "age": 25
    }
]
```

without `member.username.asc().nullsLast()` being applied.

When I switch the `orderBy` condition to

```
.orderBy(
member.username.asc().nullsLast(),
member.age.asc()
)
```

```
[
    {
        "username": "member17",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "username": "member18",
        "age": 24
    },
    {
        "username": "member19",
        "age": 23
    },
    {
        "username": "member20",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "username": "member22",
        "age": 21
    },
    {
        "username": "member23",
        "age": 21
    },
    {
        "username": "member24",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "username": null,
        "age": 17
    },
    {
        "username": null,
        "age": 21
    }
]
```

the username condition gets applied while the age condition is ignored.

If I want to apply the age condition first, and then use the username condition,
I can't simply do `member.username.nullsLast()`, Java doesn't let me and gives me this error,

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method nullsLast()
  location: variable username of type com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.StringPath
```

If I want to sort this list by `member.age.asc()` and apply `nullsLast` to username, how should I get about this?

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired output is? Both of those examples look as I would expect: the second sort criterion is applied when the first one is equal.

Comment: my desired output is somewhat following the first conditions in my where(), which is          member.age.asc(),
                        member.username.asc().nullsLast()
I want the age to be asc() and username to be nullsLast().

Comment: Please update the question with the _specific_ output you want, in a similar format to the examples of actual output.